# How to bind emacs abort to key

Tags: solaris, emacs

This is from a .el file loaded in my .emacs file. What do you think?

```
;;; Sun keyboard bindings

;; the below line does not work:
;; when <cancel> is pressed, the minibuffer echoes "Quit"
;; but that is the only thing it does

;; (global-set-key [cancel] 'keyboard-quit)

;; Note: I got the 'keyboard-quit from C-h c and then C-g
;; (C-g is the normal way for me to abort)

;; Those work, so it has probably something to do
;; with the peculiarities of 'keyboard-quit, rather than
;; the actual keybinding (or?)

(global-set-key [SunProps] 'describe-variable)
(global-set-key [SunFront] 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [SunOpen] 'list-buffers)
(global-set-key [XF86Copy] 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key [XF86Paste] 'x-clipboard-yank)
(global-set-key [XF86Cut] 'clipboard-kill-region)
```

Comment: What did you expect keyboard-quit to do?  The behavior you describe sounds normal to me.

Comment: If you hit it (the cancel button on the keyboard after doing the above stuff) it does not produce the same effect as when you do C-g. On the contrary, nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the fact that <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> has to interrupt Emacs while it's doing other things (and not reading normal input), it's hardcoded into the Emacs core and can't be rebound using normal methods.  There is a `set-quit-char` function, but it only works with ASCII characters.

```
(set-quit-char QUIT)

Specify character used for quitting.
QUIT must be an ASCII character.

This function only has an effect on the controlling tty of the Emacs
process.
```

In short, you'd have to patch and recompile Emacs to do what you want.

However, it is possible to get *some* of what you want.  If you do

```
(define-key local-function-key-map [cancel] [7]) ; 7 is C-g
```

then `cancel` should work like `C-g`, but only when Emacs is reading normal input.  It won't interrupt a long-running Elisp function the way `C-g` will.  But it will cancel a `C-x C-f` or similar command that's reading input from the minibuffer.

Comment: Wow, did I find something that was that difficult? I'm impressed! But even more so by your answer.